# Value moved in an empty expression statement

Tags: rust

On my first day of fiddling with Rust, I tried to execute an empty expression statement. The compiler threw a "value borrowed here after move" error when I tried printing the variable used inside the empty expression statement.

Here is the sample code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let tstr = String::from("test"); // "move occurs because `tstr` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait"
    tstr; // causes move? <- "value moved here"
    println!("{}",tstr); // "value borrowed here after move"
}
```

Does the empty expression call some hidden trait of the String method which takes ownership of the object? Or is something else at play here?

Comment: @tadman That wouldn't help. The move happens before that line.

Comment: It's just like any other expression: if you use `tstr` by value (not via reference) then it's moved. Think of it like `identity(tstr);`

Comment: @tadman `println!` automatically references it's arguments

Comment: @PitaJ I've seen it consume values before, except with debug (`:?`) mode, but you're right, and now I've got to adjust my expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust is generally considered to be an "[expression oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression-oriented_programming_language)" language. Broadly speaking, this means that most language constructs are *expressions*. Expressions are things that evaluate to values, and critically, do so *independent of the context that they appear in*.

A concrete consequence of this is that whether you write

```
let foo = <expression>;
```

or

```
<expression>;
```

doesn't affect<sup>1</sup> how Rust evaluates `<expression>`. In particular, it doesn't change whether evaluating `<expression>` causes a value to be moved.

Since evaluating the right-hand side of

```
let new_tstr = tstr;
```

clearly involves moving `tstr`, so to does evaluating

```
tstr;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At the language level. Rust may of course compile these statements differently so long as the observable behavior remains the same. See "[as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)."

Comment: Note that while this is true, there is a special case: `let _ = <expression>;` (and `_ = <expression>;`) **does not** moves its argument.